# Getting player instance inside event callback

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have multiple dynamically defined player instances on the same page and am trying to track *which* instance is firing the events I'm capturing so I can get the video details. The data object passed to the callback function only contains playhead position data; is there a way I'm missing to tell which player instance on the page is currently active/playing? I didn't see a `getPlaying()` function (as opposed, say, to the `getPaused()` function).

Comment: Pass  "ID" as an argument to your functions to get references of your players ...isn't it simple?

Comment: This only returns 'undefined' as it's not how a callback works. I deleted my previous 'answer' because it was a reply to this and I don't want to muddy the waters; I've now found a solution so am posting it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, so I'm posting it here in case it might help somebody - I didn't find anything in several hours of googling, so...

In retrospect I may rename my `this.currentPlayer` property to `this.activeTitle` or something more descriptive like that.

```js
export default class VimeoAnalytics{

    // initialize your players and store them in an
    // object property

    trackEvents(){
        if(this.players.length > 0){
            for(let plr of this.players){
                plr.on('play', async data => {
                    try{
                        if(data.seconds == 0){
                            this.currentPlayer = await this.getCurrentPlayer();
                            window.dataLayer.push({
                                'event': 'mwv.video',
                                'category': 'vimeoVideo',
                                'action': 'startVideo',
                                'label': this.currentPlayer,
                            });
                        }else{
                            window.dataLayer.push({
                                'event': 'mwv.video',
                                'category': 'vimeoVideo',
                                'action': 'resumeVideo',
                                'label': this.currentPlayer,
                            });
                        }
                    }catch(e){
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                });

                // from here you can use `this.currentPlayer` in the pause,
                // ended, or other triggered events.

            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Apparently autopause is a default init parameter, so when one video starts playing the
     * others stop; we can use this to determine which video is currently playing.
     * @returns String
     */
     async getCurrentPlayer(){
        for(let plyr of this.players){
            let resp = await plyr.getPaused().then(paused => paused);

            if(!resp){
                let title = await plyr.getVideoTitle().then(title => title);
                return title;
            }
        }
    }
}
```